# How to access gmail with 2-step verification?

Tags: java, email, imap

Recently I set up 2-step verification in my gmail account , and I try to connect to my gmail account using Java Mail API, but it didn't connect.

My code:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "my_account@gmail.com", "password");
        System.out.println(store);

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
        for (Message message : messages) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    }
```

And what i get from logcat:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Application-specific password required: http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=185833 (Failure)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:660)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
```

What is the method to overcome this issue, please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

When you have activated 2-step verification for gmail account, login to the below link using your gmail credentials and generate application specific password (ASP). You can use the generated password in your code. Simply add the ASP in place of the normal password. It should work.

https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hide_authsub=1

**Update** : 30-July 2018

When you open this link and login once with the gmail id and password manually, you will see this page as shown below. Select "Mail" option in the first drop down

[image]

In the second drop down, select the platform based on your requirement, Say "Windows Computer" or "Mac"

[image]

Then, Click the generate button and you will see a code with 16 alphabets in the next screen.

Use this as a password in your java mail program like this

```js
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "gmail id used in the previous step", "16 alphabets code");
```

Comment: Is there a javamail api where we can send the second step verification code .

Comment: Please provide an example.